# Junit restcotroller test method

Tags: java, rest, junit

I have question,
I create a junit test for my controller method but i'm not sure that this test look good. Test pass ok but the body is not clear for me.
This is my method which i want to test:

```
@PostMapping("/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> addPeopleToTeam(@PathVariable Long teamId, @PathVariable Long personId) {
        TeamsAndPersonsId teamsAndPersonsId = new TeamsAndPersonsId(personId, teamId);
        teamService.findTeamById(teamsAndPersonsId.getTeamId());
        personService.findById(teamsAndPersonsId.getPersonId());
        teamService.addPersonsToTeams(personId, teamId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(teamsAndPersonsId);

    }
```

And this is my test:

```
@Test
    public void shouldAddPersonToTeam() throws Exception {
        // Given
        TeamDto teamDto = prepareTeamDto();
        PersonDto personDto = preparePersonDto();
        // When
        verify(teamService, times(0)).createTeam(teamDto);
        teamService.createTeam(any());
        verify(personService, times(0)).addPerson(personDto);
        personService.addPerson(any());
        // than
        mockMvc.perform(post("/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}", 1, 1))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

    private PersonDto preparePersonDto() {
        return new PersonDto(1L, "Bob", "Noob", "mail@first.pl", "Warszawa", "APPS", "Developer");
    }

    private TeamDto prepareTeamDto() {
        return new TeamDto(1L, "Jan", "local", "wawa", 6);
    }
```

This is not a stupid idea that i have times 0? This mean that I call the method 0 times? Smb know how to correct this test to checked add person to teams?

Comment: Yes, it seems stupid. Also I don't what TeamDto and PersonDto is used for. `addPeopleToTeam` only needs `id`s, not DTOs

Comment: I use this dto to other test's in this case i only need an id that's true. But i don't know how to fix this method to look's good.

Comment: Then, I would just check the response to be successfull. No DTOs nor verifications. Also, you could check the response body: assert that `teamsAndPersonsId.getTeamId() == 1` and `teamsAndPersonsId.getPersonId == 1`.

Comment: unfortunately when i try all is red and doesn't compile :/

Comment: when(teamService.createTeam(teamDto)).thenReturn(Reponse.ok().build()); - I make somthing like this but Response is not identify

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@After + verifyNoMoreInteractions** method to make sure no other method other then what you "**expected**" is called.

Any method annotated with @After, will be called after each method marked as @Test. (i.e. after each test case)

verifyNoMoreInteractions, tell that if any method (other then the 3 method) other that what was expected of mocks passed as param (teamService and personService) is called, then fail the testcase.

```
@After
public void teamdown() {
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(teamService, personService);
}
```

NOTE : Assuming, the when and verify part of Unit test you already know/figured out. Let me know if you need help there.